# Why is my code halting?

Tags: java, swing

I'm testing my code with JFrame and after it has run and I input the values, it's neither sending the value to my MS sql management studio or crashing. I've created the connection in the submit button of my code, I've tried creating the connection in the class that deal with the insert also and same result. The code from the Insert class works fine without JFrame.

```
public void initialize() 
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 345);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lblChasis = new JLabel("Chasis num:");
        JLabel lblEngNum = new JLabel("Engine num:");
        JLabel lblMake = new JLabel("Make:");
        JLabel lblModel = new JLabel("Model:");
        JLabel lblYear = new JLabel("Year od car:");
        JLabel lblCapacity = new JLabel("Capacity:");
        JLabel lblSupplier = new JLabel("Supplier ID:");
        JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel("Status:");

        txtChasisNum = new JTextField();
        txtChasisNum.setColumns(10);

        txtEngNum = new JTextField();
        txtEngNum.setColumns(10);

        txtYear = new JTextField();
        txtYear.setColumns(10);

        txtModel = new JTextField();
        txtModel.setColumns(10);

        txtMake = new JTextField();
        txtMake.setColumns(10);

        txtStatus = new JTextField();
        txtStatus.setColumns(10);

        txtSupplier = new JTextField();
        txtSupplier.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Insert I = new Insert();
                try
                {
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DEEZY\\SQLEXPRESS;user=Java1234;password=barcelona;database=car_inventory");

                    chasisNnum = txtChasisNum.getText();
                    engNum = txtEngNum.getText();
                    year_of_car = txtYear.getText();  
                    model = txtModel.getText(); 
                    make = txtMake.getText();
                    capacity = txtCapacity.getText();
                    description = txtDescription.getText();
                    statTxt = txtStatus.getText();
                    sup_id = Integer.parseInt(statTxt);
                    supTxt =txtSupplier.getText();
                    status = Integer.parseInt(supTxt);

                    I.insertVehicle(engNum, chasisNnum, make, model, year_of_car, capacity, sup_id, status, description,con);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException n) 
                {

                }
                catch(Exception e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        JLabel lblDescription = new JLabel("Description");

        txtDescription = new JTextField();
        txtDescription.setColumns(10);

        txtCapacity = new JTextField();
        txtCapacity.setColumns(10);

);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
        frame.add(btnSubmit);

    }//end of Initialize
```

method from the insert class:

```
public void insertVehicle(String engNum, String chasisNum,String make,String model,String year,String capacity,int supId,int status,String description,Connection Con) 
    {
        try
        {
            CallableStatement ct = Con.prepareCall("{Call addVehicle(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
            ct.setString(1, engNum);
            ct.setString(2,chasisNum);
            ct.setString(3,make);
            ct.setString(4,model);
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date dt = format.parse(year);
            ct.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime()));
            ct.setString(6,capacity);
            ct.setInt(7, supId);
            ct.setInt(8, status);
            ct.setString(9,description);
            System.out.println(ct.execute());

        }//end of try 

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }// end of catch

    }//end of insert into vehile
```

Comment: might i ask where you add `btnNewButton` to your actuell panel? since it´s not clear from your code how you get the submit buttong into your panel. (or even any swing element)

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through your code to see on what line it hangs?

Comment: And please also do something in your `catch (NumberFormatException n) ` , you probably don't want to get an exception , and not know about it - especially while you're trying to find issues with your code.

Comment: The driver class name looks wrong; try `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver`.